# keep getting error when trying to install gems on osx, undefined method `ord' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I am using rvm on osx, I have only one version of ruby currently installed 2.0.0
and every gem install I try to run comes back with the same result:

```
guys-MacBook-Pro:guy guy$ rvm use
Using /Users/guy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353

guys-MacBook-Pro:guy guy$ gem install proxylocal
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `ord' for nil:NilClass
```

please help

thanks

update:

```
guys-MacBook-Pro:guy guy$ gem install -V proxylocal
GET https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=proxylocal
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=proxylocal
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=bert
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=bert
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=eventmachine
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=eventmachine
200 OK
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
 undefined method `ord' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: hi @BroiSatse, how can I see the trace? --trace isn't working for that command...

Comment: Usually stacktrace is just below the error, is the above snippet all you got?

Comment: yes. included every output the terminal gave me

Comment: Try running `gem install -V proxylocal`

Comment: ran the command and updated my question. thanks

Comment: tried 2 others macs and got the same result

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9498#change-45180) with ruby-2.x.x. Refer more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32233444/2036529).